# Idea intelliJ for chef development

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to using Idea IntelliJ 2016.3 for chef developmemt but can't see any plugin which can help me get started. Is there any plugin I can use to start with chef development?

I tried https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1293-ruby and then https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7548-chef-integration . Downloaded the zips and tried to install from the local repo but it says `Plugin is not compatible with the installation` . I used the latest downloadables.

Answer (score 0):

No need to download from external links. Can be done from IDE interface

> Go to Add plugins in setting or press Ctrl+Alt+S
>   Plugins
>   Search Chef Integration
>   If not found search in the repositories
>   Screenshot 2 [image: After Search IDEAv2017.1]

Screenshot 1 [image: Before Search IDEAv2017.1]

Comment: Chef integration plugin is not available when I search for it. I am using community edition , not sure if its because of that.

Comment: Yeahh, it is incompatible with community edition. You can check compatible products from jetBrains for chef Integration. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7548-chef-integration/update/30095

Comment: well this link shows intellij community edition as compatible isn't it? `com.intellij.modules.ruby, com.intellij.modules.ultimate` are incompatible.